# Why do we reshape data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, reshape

I have got a dataset which consists of 100,000 rows and 12 columns, where each column stands of a certain input to train a sequential GRU model to predict only 1 output. The following is the code for the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(units=70, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,12),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(GRU(units=50, return_sequences=True,dropout=0.1))
model.add(GRU(units=30, dropout=0.1))
model.add(Dense(units=5))
model.add(Dense(units=3))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss=['mae'], optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),metrics=['mse']) 
model.summary() 
history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=1000,epochs=30,validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)
```

However, before that I had to transform the training dataset from 2D to 3D using  `x_train=x.reshape(-1,1,12)` and the output from 1D to 2D using `y_train=y.reshape(-1,1)`. That is the part I really don't understand, why not just keep them as they are?

Answer (score 1):

You had to describe your data in order to be decisive.
But since each layers output is the input of the next layer, their shape must be equal. In the incomplete example you gave your labels need to be a single value for each sample and I think that's why reshape was used.

Comment: Sorry to make sure I understand correctly. Since we have 12 inputs and only 1 output, both input and output have to be the same shape? For example input is 100000x1x12 3-D and output is 100,000x1 2-D. Sorry if my question was vague, would gladly give whatever more information you need. Thank you.

Comment: [This link](https://www.kaggle.com/shivajbd/input-and-output-shape-in-lstm-keras) has good descriptions for dimensions in LSTM.